# Exemplar MLE for negative binomial?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, negative-binomial-distribution

I recently compared MLE estimates for a negative binomial fit using two different pieces of software, and got different results.  I'd like to determine which (if either) is correct.

To do that, I'd like an example of a simple set of data along with the corresponding MLE solution.  I'd really like an analytic proof of the optimality of the MLE solution, since determining it with some third software library seems a bit circular.  However, we are free to choose any data that might make the analysis work out nicely.

For the record, I noticed the discrepancy through these snippets of code ([first library](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html) in R, [second library](https://github.com/gokceneraslan/fit_nbinom) in Python).  The data was {2,4} (i.e., I only fit two data points).

```
library(MASS)
x=fitdistr(c(2,4),"Negative Binomial")
p = x$estimate['size'][[1]] / (x$estimate['size'][[1]] + x$estimate['mu'][[1]])
# Results:
# > p
# [1] 0.9708738
# > x
#      size         mu    
#   100.00020     3.00000 
#  (505.70845) (  1.24298)
```

and

```
import fit_nbinom
x = fit_nbinom.fit_nbinom(np.array([2,4]))
mu = ((1.0-x['prob'])/x['prob'])  * x['size']
# Results:
# In []: x
# Out[]: {'prob': 0.98892868281051893, 'size': 270.37321834245245}
#
# In []: mu
# Out[]: 3.026899423427535
```

Comment: It's not apparent that you did get different results: the differences are well within the reported standard errors, suggesting the explanation may lie with floating point imprecision.  Indeed, if you rerun the `r` version with different starting values or different precision and accuracy requirements, you will get different results, too. In such circumstances it can help to provide input data where you have an exact *analytical* solution available for comparison. Have you worked out the exact solution for your sample data?

Comment: I think this is precisely my question, @whuber, (i.e., could somebody please help me find an exact analytical solution).  The errors appear to be about 1% in the mean (and a factor of >two in the "size" parameter), so it seems surprising if this were a function of floating point precision.  (At least for the Python code, I would expect errors several orders of magnitude smaller.)

Comment: In this case $\hat{\mu} = 3$ IS the MLE, so that 3.0268... from Python is wrong.  (It is always the case that the sample mean is the MLE for $\mu$ in that parameterization of the NB.)   A roughly 1% relative error when you only have two data points of the same order of magnitude is pretty large... I suspect the code iterates to a not-very-tight convergence criterion.  Iteration is required for the solution of the MLE equations for the NB, so you won't find an exact analytic solution.

Answer (score 1):

The negative binomial density is:

$$f(x) = \Gamma(x + n )/(\Gamma(n) x!) p^n (1-p)^x$$

So for your sample:

$$L([2,4]) = f(2)f(4) \propto \Gamma(2 + n )\Gamma(4 + n )/2\Gamma(n)( p^{2n} (1-p)^6 ) $$

which we are to maximize

The mean is 3 by default as others have noted. Define a few useful R wrappers:

```
loglik <- function(size) sum(dnbinom(c(2,4), size=size, mu=3, log=T))
```

and just visualize what happens over a range of "size"

```
plot(1:1000, sapply(1:1000, loglik), type='l', xlab='Size parameter', ylab='Trace of log likelihood')
```

[image]

You can see the likelihood approaches an asymptote and has no unique, finite maximum.

Comment: As a follow-on comment - the sample variance (1) is less than the sample mean (3), which I believe always causes the MLE to exhibit this behavior.